# How to call setUndecorated() while application is running?

Tags: java, swing, jframe

Hi I'm not such a professional at programming so i come here to ask how i can make this possible.

Issue: Client game is running once fullscreen mode clicked i want it to call setUndecorated() but cant while the frame is already visible.

I realized that i would need to create a new frame but im unsure how to transfer everything over, i have tried myself and all i get is a blank white screen of the new frame.

Here is my code:

```
public Jframe(String args[]) {
    super();
    try {
        sign.signlink.startpriv(InetAddress.getByName(server));
        initUI();
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public void initUI() {
    try {
        UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
        JPopupMenu.setDefaultLightWeightPopupEnabled(false);
        frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        this.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
        gamePanel = new JPanel();
        gamePanel.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        gamePanel.add(this);
        JMenu fileMenu = new JMenu("Menu");

        String[] mainButtons = new String[] { "-", "Donate", "-", "Vote", "-", "Hiscores", "-", "Forums", "-", "Exit"};

        for (String name : mainButtons) {
            JMenuItem menuItem = new JMenuItem(name);
            if (name.equalsIgnoreCase("-")) {
                fileMenu.addSeparator();
            } else {
                menuItem.addActionListener(this);
                fileMenu.add(menuItem);
            }
        }

        JMenuBar menuBar = new JMenuBar();
        JMenuBar jmenubar = new JMenuBar();
        Jframe.frame.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(773, 556));
        frame.add(jmenubar);
        menuBar.add(fileMenu);
        frame.getContentPane().add(menuBar, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        frame.getContentPane().add(gamePanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        frame.pack();

        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setResizable(true);
        init();
    } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

I hope any of you can help i really appreciate thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If this is for a game then most likely you don't want this. You should take a look at 
http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/fullscreen/exclusivemode.html

Answer (score 0):

I may be pointing out the obvious, as well as facilitating the wrong approach, but can't you just make it not visible then make it visible again?

i.e.

```
myFrame.setVisible(false);
myFrame.setUndecorated(true);
myFrame.setVisible(true);
```

However, there is a better approach, as "ghostbust555" pointed out.

This is the `setFullScreenWindow()` that answer was referring to:

```
public void goFullScreen() {
    GraphicsDevice myDevice =
        GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment().getDefaultScreenDevice();

    // wrap in try because we don't want to lock the app in fullscreen mode
    try {
        myDevice.setFullScreenWindow(myFrame);

        // do your stuff
        ...

    } finally {
        myDevice.setFullScreenWindow(null);
    }
}
```

Comment: myFrame.setVisible(false);
myFrame.setUndecorated(true);
myFrame.setVisible(true);
That does not work; it still throws the error.